# Angular6 POST request remains in pending status

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, angular6, asp.net-core-2.2

Hello I am trying to post request from angular6 to asp.net core web api, but unfortunately the request never receives on server and always remains in "pending" status.

My model at server:

```cs
public class MainVM
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Logo { get; set; }
        public List<ChildVM> ListChilds { get; set; }

}

public class ChildVM
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int SequenceNo { get; set; }
        public int NoOfPrices { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
}
```

and the end point:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public void Post([FromForm]MainVM data)
{
}
```

Angular6 service that I am using to post data from angular:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    //formData.append('Logo', logo, logo.name);
    formData.append('Name', obj.Name);
    formData.append('ListChilds[0].Name', obj.ListChilds[0].Name);
    formData.append('ListChilds[0].SequenceNo', String(obj.ListChilds[0].SequenceNo));
    formData.append('ListChilds[0].NoOfPrices', String(obj.ListChilds[0].NoOfPrices));



    return this.http.post<MainVM>('http://localhost:60458/api/mycontroller/', formData).pipe(
      map((res) => { console.log('res'); return res; }),
      catchError(this.handleError('lpc', null))
    );
```

When I comment out code related to ListChilds in formData the request receives at the web api but the request does not receive at web api with ListChilds.

I think I am missing something.

Please guide.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 formData.append('ListChilds', JSON.stringify(obj.ListChilds));
```

It should populate all the values from obj.ListChilds into ListChilds.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried it now the request receives at the server but the parameters of ListChilds are null

Comment: Sorry I do not have a machine with angular, and can't install either. But my best guess is obj.ListChild might not have the same structure as ListChilds of your MainVM. To test that simply print _JSON.stringify(obj.ListChilds)_ and check the resulting JSON. It should have similar structure to your model.

Comment: The structures are same for both client and server side.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it turned out that it is a bug in Asp.net Core 2.2, I have found it here:

> https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4802

The issue is when we took IFormFile type in child model, the Asp.net core 2.2 program starts to hang (as described in the link above).

As a work around I remove following line from ChildVM:

```
public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
```

and added the following line in MainVM:

```
public List<IFormFile> ListImage { get; set; }
```